# Clojure lazy seq consumption from different positions in the body of a function

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, lazy-sequences

Clojure beginner here, not sure if the terminology in the question is even correct.

I'm building a web scraper using the clj-webdriver taxi api. There are several sites that it needs to scrape data from. The following isn't actually code from the project, but I've tested it and verified that it illustrates my question:

```
(def gh-un "my-username")
(def gh-pw "my-password")

;; print the first five "starred" alerts from my github feed
(defn get-info [url]
  (to url)
  (click "a[href='/login']")
  (input-text "input#login_field" gh-un)
  (input-text "input#password" gh-pw)
  (click "input.btn")
  (pprint (map text (take 5 (find-elements {:css "div.alert.watch_started"}))))
  (click "img.avatar")
  (click "button.dropdown-signout"))

(defn github-wrapper []
  (map get-info (repeat 3 "http://www.github.com"))
  (quit))
```

If I call `(github-wrapper)` as is, the browser window will close almost immediately, because of the `(quit)` call. Wrapping the `map` call with `doall`, i.e. `(doall (map get-info (repeat 3 "http://www.github.com")))`, solves this problem, which suggests that the problem is that map produces a lazy sequence that's not getting consumed, and therefore I'm not seeing the side-effects of the calls to `get-info`.

However, if I remove the `(quit)` call at the end of `get-info`, `github-wrapper` does what I want it to.

My question is, why does the lazy sequence get consumed in the latter case, but not in the former?

Comment: Probably, it's because you're running your code in REPL, so your lazy sequence is returned from `github-wrapper` and then evaluated and printed by the REPL.

Comment: I was indeed running the code in the REPL.  I don't have this script set up to run from the command line yet, but I will be sure to test this once I do.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are probably printing the returned map when you call `github-wrapper`. Printing a lazy sequence is one way (along with `doall`) to consume it. When you put `quit` at the end of `github-wrapper`, that is what gets returned and the map just assumes that nothing requires its values.

You can also use `mapv` instead of `map` if you want your map to be immediately realized.